# Choose hours in the whole month pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I was working with a data frame containing timestamp of one day `2016-06-01`

And to get a specific hour I was doing the following:

```
df1 = df[(df.timestamp > '2016-06-01 00:00:00') & (df.timestamp < '2016-06-01 01:00:00')]
```

Now, I have merged a lot of data frames and now I have the whole month, from `06-01` to `06-30`.

How I should rewrite the code? I tried ti delete the part with `2016-06-01` but it is not working I am getting empty data frame.

Question:

Want to get new dataframe of a given hour for the whole dataset.

P.S. Not sure about second question here but anyway. 
Even I will be able to do that, I save every hour separately, so I have 24 dataframes. Any easy method to run the same code 24 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [pandas.DataFrame.between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html)

For example, in your case:

```py
i = pd.date_range('2016-06-01', periods=4, freq='1D40min')
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, index=i)

df.between_time('0:00', '1:00')
```